# Cannot edit column values in dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

I am not able to update the values of columns in dataGridView. please help

```
          private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

           {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            itemRecordBindingSource.EndEdit();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Update(dt);    
            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved.");
        }

        catch(Exception c)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Sorry, could not update data." + c);
        }

    }
```

Its not showing any error, also not updating the table.

Comment: plase paste full code and here I dont see how you are assigining data back to datatable?

Comment: This is the line of code for the database, there's nothing more code in this form.

` private void itemedit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            this.itemRecordTableAdapter.Fill(this.managementDataSet2.ItemRecord);

        }
`

Comment: so how you supose to do it ? you are creating a black dataTable and sending to to adapter  and how you expect an update ?

Comment: Also sending update of entire datagridview is not a good solution . if you are looking say if you edit few column on gridview and then they automaticaly gets updated in database then .I can tell you correct way for that

Comment: How can i do that, in this case, for example i want to show a complete table in datagridview and want to edit some value.

Comment: I added my answer please check it will solve your problem . if you have any more question let me know .

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your datagrid editable and after you edit a column in grid you want to save it to db please use this event of grid view .

```
 I am assuming you are able to fill GridView with data if not first 
 get the data from sql query and set the datasource of grifview to that table . once you have data then you can use this event .


        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
            -- here you can get the column index and column value 
            now based on the index and value you can witre you sql query / or a function which will update the database . 
            string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```